# Get User Count for a Google Apps Domain

Tags: google-apps

How do you get the total number of users in a Google Apps Domain? I'm aware of the ["Retrieve All Users in Domain" call](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference.html) using the Google Provisioning API, but I'd rather not execute such an intensive call just to count up all the users. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that isn't as resource-heavy as retrieving all users: The [Google Reporting API](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/reporting/google_apps_reporting_api.html#Summary_Report) can be used to get the total number of accounts in a Google Apps domain.

Answer (score 3):

The Google Apps Admin Settings API allows you to retrieve both the current and maximum number of users in the domain:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-settings/#retrieving_the_current_number_of_users_in_a_domain

this would be preferable to the reports API as it's both lower in traffic and it's closer to real time (reports are only updated every 24 hours so it won't take into account users recently added).

Comment: This looks like the preferable method indeed, but requires to add a scope (`https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/`) to the OAuth permissions. Which will force all current users to update access-grant. Is there another way to do it within the standard scopes?

Comment: This API is being deprecated for [this](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-customers).

Answer (score 2):

You could try "Retrieve All Nicknames in Domain" which could save some bandwidth as it hopefully really only retrieves the nicknames, although I think this won't get you the exact count because "Retrieve All Nicknames for a User" seems to imply that a user can have multiple nicknames.

If you've got some test domain, also assure that retrieving all users really is too much overhead and keep in mind that depending on what you want to do, you can perhaps build some kind of cache around it that only does a full request after the cache is older than X.